# Definition of def, cdef and cpdef in Cython

Tags: python, declaration, cython

What is the difference between `def`, `cdef` and `cpdef` when I declare a function?

The difference between def and the others is more or less clear. And I've also seen that sometimes it's added the return type in the declaration (`cdef void/double/int... name`) and sometimes not.

How can I declare a string variable in Cython, as I didn't know it? I declared it as object.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`def` declares a function in Python. Since Cython is based on C runtime, it allows you to use `cdef` and `cpdef`.

`cdef` declares function in the layer of C language. As you know (or not?) in C language you have to define type of returning value for each function. Sometimes function returns with `void`, and this is equal for just `return` in Python.

Python is an object-oriented language. So you also can define class method in layer of C++ language, and override this methods in subclasses:

```
cdef class A:
    cdef foo(self):
        print "A"

cdef class B(A)
    cdef foo(self, x=None)
        print "B", x

cdef class C(B):
    cpdef foo(self, x=True, int k=3)
        print "C", x, k
```

Summary, why do we need to use `def`, `cdef` and `cpdef`? Because if you use Cython, your Python code will be converted into C code before compile. So with this things you can control the resulting C-code listing.

For more information I suggest you to read the official documentation: http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/language_basics.html

Comment: Python code never gets converted to `C`, it's just get converted to python `bytecode` and evaluated by python interpreter written in `C`.

Comment: @gsb-eng We were talking about Cython, not Python. `Cython works by producing a standard Python module. However, the behavior differs from standard Python in that the module code, originally written in Python, is translated into C.` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cython#Design

Comment: Answer does not describe cpdef differences from cdef

Answer (score 88):

The key difference is in where the function can be called from: `def` functions can be called from Python and Cython while `cdef` function can be called from Cython and C.

Both types of functions can be declared with any mixture of typed and untyped arguments, and in both cases the internals are compiled to C by Cython (and the compiled code should be very, very similar):

```
# A Cython class for illustrative purposes
cdef class C:
   pass

def f(int arg1, C arg2, arg3):
    # takes an integer, a "C" and an untyped generic python object
    pass

cdef g(int arg1, C arg2, arg3):
    pass
```

In the example above, `f` will be visible to Python (once it has imported the Cython module) and `g` will not be and cannot be called from Python. `g` will translate into a C signature of:

```
PyObject* some_name(int, struct __pyx_obj_11name_of_module_C *, PyObject*)
```

(where `struct __pyx_obj_11name_of_module_C *` is just the C struct that our class `C` is translated into). This allows it to be passed to C functions as a function pointer for example. In contrast `f` cannot (easily) be called from C.

**Restrictions on `cdef` functions:**

`cdef` functions cannot be defined inside other functions - this is because there is no way of storing any captured variables in a C function pointer. E.g. the following code is illegal:

```
# WON'T WORK!
def g(a):
   cdef (int b):
      return a+b
```

`cdef` functions cannot take `*args` and `**kwargs` type arguments. This is because they cannot easily be translated into a C signature.

**Advantages of `cdef` functions**

`cdef` functions can take any type of argument, including those that have no Python equivalent (for example pointers). `def` functions cannot have these, since they must be callable from Python.

`cdef` functions can also specify a return type (if it is not specified then they return a Python object, `PyObject*` in C). `def` functions always return a Python object, so cannot specify a return type:

```
cdef int h(int* a):
    # specify a return type and take a non-Python compatible argument
    return a[0]
```

`cdef` functions are quicker to call than `def` functions because they translate to a simple C function call.

**`cpdef` functions**

`cpdef` functions cause Cython to generate a `cdef` function (that allows a quick function call from Cython) and a `def` function (which allows you to call it from Python). Interally the `def` function just calls the `cdef` function. In terms of the types of arguments allowed, `cpdef` functions have all the restrictions of both `cdef` and `def` functions.

**When to use a `cdef` function**

Once the function has been called there is no difference in the speed that the code inside a `cdef` and a `def` function runs at. Therefore, only use a `cdef` function if:

- You need to pass non-Python types in or out, or
- You need to pass it to C as a function pointer, or
- You are calling it often (so the sped-up function call is important) and you don't need to call it from Python.

Use a `cpdef` function when you are calling it often (so the sped-up function call is important) but you do need to call it from Python.

Comment: I've interpreted and re-used your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49172528/should-i-define-my-cython-function-using-def-cdef-or-cpdef-for-optimal-perform/49172529#49172529
Can you perhaps double-check it?

Comment: @PDiracDelta I did see that. It looks like a useful question/answer combination (in my opinion a lot of people use `cdef` for because they think it's automatically faster for no real reason so it's good to have a simple summary). I can't see anything I disagree with there