# why is cpdef not used with __init__ in cython

Tags: cython

Had a basic question after reading the Cython documentation on classes, but I thought to get it clear. Here is a sample code from the [Cython documentation](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/early_binding_for_speed.html):

```
cdef class Rectangle:
    cdef int x0, y0
    cdef int x1, y1
    def __init__(self, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1):
        self.x0 = x0; self.y0 = y0; self.x1 = x1; self.y1 = y1
    cpdef int area(self):
        cdef int area
        area = (self.x1 - self.x0) * (self.y1 - self.y0)
        if area < 0:
            area = -area
        return area
```

Why is the `__init__` preceded by `def` and not `cdef` or `cpdef`?

I realize that there is a `__cinit__` function, but shouldn't making `cpdef __init__` make the `__init__` code faster?

Or, are we supposed to put the code, that we need to make very fast, in the `__cinit__` section and the code, which we can afford to run slower, in the `__init__` section?

Comment: `__init__` and `__cinit__` are the constructors of your object. In a well designed program you usually do not have any time critical calculations in a constructor. Also `__cinit__` and `__init__` are not equivalent. If you have to initialize `c` parts of your objects (e.g. a `malloc`) then this happens in `__cinit__` and normal python initialization happens in `__init__`

Comment: i understand this (and this is in the documentation too). what i wanted to ask is that why codes use `def __init__` instead of say `cpdef __init__`

Comment: I am not sure if `cpdef __init__` even works. apart from that - I don't see a reason for doing that. Why would you prefer `cpdef`?

Answer (score 1):

`cpdef` does not affect the speed of the code inside the function. It only creates a version of the function that can be called directly from C/Cython (without having to go through the Python call mechanism). The "inside" of the function is compiled in both cases and runs at exactly the same speed. See [Definition of def, cdef and cpdef in cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28362009/definition-of-def-cdef-and-cpdef-in-cython/41976772#41976772) for a full discussion.

Most Cython special functions (those with names of the form `__xxx__`) are restricted to being defined as `def` functions. Essentially because they serve a special purpose to the Python interpreter and Cython won't be able to use the C shortcut version. `__init__` is no exception - it's part of the normal Python construction mechanism and so it only make senses to call it as a Python method.

`__cinit__` is a slightly odd case - it can only be invoked by the Cython (implicitly) and cannot be called by the user. It therefore isn't really either a normal `def`, `cdef` or `cpdef` method. It's therefore just a matter of language design what keyword is used to define it (whatever you chose, it'd always be called in the same way anyway). In terms of what arguments it accepts it behaves like a `def` function though since it can handle `*args` and `**kwds` but only types that can be directly converted from Python objects (i.e. not C pointers).

---

If you can to make an alternate `cdef` (or `cpdef`) `staticmethod` constructor to be called directly from Cython you can. [This is discussed in the documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#existing-pointers-instantiation).