# Should I define my Cython function using def, cdef, or cpdef for optimal performance?

Tags: function, cython, definition, function-definition

How can I know whether to use def, cdef or cpdef when defining a Cython function, assuming I want optimal performance?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you want optimal performance, you should know that as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28362009/definition-of-def-cdef-and-cpdef-in-cython/41976772#41976772) to a related question:

> Once the function has been called there is no difference in the speed that the code inside a `cdef` and a `def` function runs at.

So for optimal Cython performance you should **always statically type all arguments and variables**, and intuitively you would then be tempted to use `cdef`, but there are some caveats for which I constructed the flowchart below (also based on previously mentioned answer):

[image: def, cdef, cpdef flowchart]

Furthermore, note that:

> `cpdef` functions cause Cython to generate a `cdef` function (that allows a quick function call from Cython) and a `def` function (which allows you to call it from Python). Interally the `def` function just calls the `cdef` function.

... and from the Cython documentation:

> This exploits early binding so that `cpdef` functions may be as fast as possible when using C fundamental types (by using `cdef`). `cpdef` functions use dynamic binding when passed Python objects and this might much slower, perhaps as slow as `def` declared functions.

There exists also a [*case-specific* benchmark](http://notes-on-cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fibo_speed.html#benchmarks) (calling the function often and from Python) which yields the following result:

[image]

Comment: Give this man a medal