Monkey-patching internal classes in Python
I use the function lxml.etree.fromstring(str) that returns an instance of lxml.etree._Element. I want to add a few convenience functions to all lxml.etree._Element objects, but seem unable to do so.
Here's what I have tried and the error I get:
import lxml.etree

class CustomEtreeElement(lxml.etree._Element):

    def do_something_new(self):
        print('no problemo')

lxml.etree._Element = CustomEtreeElement


obj = lxml.etree.fromstring('<Foo><Bar>Baz</Bar></Foo>')

type(obj)
# <class 'lxml.etree._Element'>

obj.do_something_new()
# AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'do_something_new'

Update:
I have settled for not patching the existing _Element class, but instead wrapping it in another class which passes through every undefined function (using __getattr__) to its internal _Element-object:
from lxml import etree

class ExtendedLxmlEtreeElement:

    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
        
    def __getattr__(self, name: str):
        return self.obj.__getattribute__(name)
    
    def do_something_new(self):
        for e in self.iter():
            print(f"e.tag:    {repr(e.tag)}\ne.prefix: {repr(e.prefix)}\ne.attrib: {repr(e.attrib)}\ne.text:   {repr(e.text)}\n")

obj = ExtendedLxmlEtreeElement(etree.fromstring('<Foo><Bar>Baz</Bar></Foo>'))

obj.find('.//Bar')  # <Element Bar at 0x2509070af00>
obj.do_something_new()  # works!

Downside to this approach is that it's not a plug-and-play solution, but in my case it works well enough.

the problem with doing this: lxml.etree._Element = CustomEtreeElement is that you cannot guarantee that the internals of the library are accessing _Element from the lxml.etree namespace (it could have been defined there, but put in some container, e.g. some registry internally, or perhaps, it is imported using from whatever import MyClass, so if you update whatever, it won't affect the code there. You could try just adding the methods to the class directly though, in this case

From my view lxml is a bit too complex library for creating inheritance, because as far as I understood it is importing methods directly from C++ and thus they are not very transparent. So I would go with adding class methods with __getattr__ or __getattribute__. Read about them and let me know if this solution works for you.
Below I'm sharing an example of the code that might be addressed for your question.
import lxml
from lxml import etree

from typing import Any


class CustomEtree():

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._Element =  etree.fromstring('<Foo><Bar>Baz</Bar></Foo>')
        
    def __getattribute__(self, name: str) -> Any:
        
        if name == 'do_something_new':
            print ("new function")
            custom_func = lambda: 123
            return custom_func
        
        #  this pattern must be used instead self._Element
        obj = super().__getattribute__('_Element') # same as self.etree

        return obj.__getattribute__(name)
    

obj = CustomEtree()
obj.do_something_new() # 123
obj.findall('Foo Foo Foo Foo') # do usual stuff



Thank you for your help. Unfortunately the code above yields and error when running obj = CustomEtree(): AttributeError: module 'lxml' has no attribute 'etree' (Python 3.12.3). And it adds the new function to an lxml.etree, not to an lxml.etree._Element.

Hello, thx for the comment. Honestly, I have the same error: 'lxml' has no attribute 'etree' when running your code snippet. Thus I'm guessing that you are using very specific version of lxml. But your own code is working on your computer?

Using __getattr__ was a good idea; I have used it to make a wrapper class (see my update to the question). I didn't want to implement all the constructor methods from lxml.etree (like fromstring()) so I just pass a _Element to the wrapper class.

My original code wasn't working on my computer either. I have also updated that; from lxml include etree seems to be the way to go. I guess I still had old objects lingering around in my interactive IDE.

Glad that you solved the issue.

You can't access it from lxml, because etree module is written in pure cython (the code is stored in .pyx files). And same for the Element class as well. And that is why they are not easily accessible. Check the file lxml/etree.pyx line 698 for definition of _Element

That does explain a lot! I see def and cdef functions don't necessarily play well together (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41976772/24702236). I'm curious now and I'll take a deeper look into Cython in my free time.
